# Using values from Select Statement in a String for a Stored Procedure - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a drop Procedure in SQL Server, but have hit a problem, in order to drop an index you must pass the table name in. I have wrote a piece of code to find the table (which works)

```
set @sqlndex = N'select name from sys.objects where object_id = (select object_id from sys.indexes where name = ''' + @objectname + ''')';
```

But I cant seem to take the returned value and use it, the code below is the full Procedure part I am working on:

What it should do:

It should print the table name (Testing reason / debugging)

It should then pass the name of the table to the drop string (+@result+)

```
 if @objecttype='index' begin
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysindexes WHERE name = @objectname)
       set @sqlndex = N'select name from sys.objects where object_id = (select object_id from sys.indexes where name = ''' + @objectname + ''')';

       execute sp_executesql @sqlndex, @result = @result OUTPUT;
       SELECT @result;
       print @result;

       set @SQL = 'DROP ' +  @objecttype  + ' [dbo].['+@result+'].['+@objectname+']';
       select @SQL;
       EXEC (@SQL);
       end
```

Variables I am declaring

```
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @sqlndex NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @resultOUT NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @objecttype VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @objectname VARCHAR(MAX);
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Instead of

```
set @sqlndex = N'select name from sys.objects
    where object_id = (select object_id from sys.indexes 
                      where name = ''' + @objectname + ''')';
```

Write:

```
declare @result nvarchar(100)
declare @paramdef nvarchar(100)

set @sqlndex = N'select @resultout = name from sys.objects
    where object_id = (select object_id from sys.indexes
                      where name = ''' + @objectname + ''')';
set @paramdef = N'@resultout nvarchar(100) output';
execute sp_executesql @sqlndex, @paramdef, @resultout = @result OUTPUT;
```

So you'll be able to manage `@result` value

Comment: I did as you suggested but I got an error "Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@result"." I have added the variables I am declaring to my question above, Any idea ?

Comment: Still getting the same error Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@result".

Comment: @Jamiex304: My fault, I've updated my answer again (sorry I'm tired, in Italy we have passed midnight)

Comment: Yes it work thanks a lot man (You just let me get some much need sleep)